# How many landings per year are performed using the integrated standby instrument system?

Tags: safety, emergency, equipment, failures

Could you tell me how many landings are exclusively driven by Integrated Standby Instrument System or equivalent in the world per year ?

Same question with "partially" using instead of "exclusively".

Comment: Hello Yan, welcome to aviation.stackexchange! I have made a few changes to the title and the text, I hope it is in line with what you intended it to be.

Comment: Yes thank you DL. It surely is better written and still is in line :-)

Answer (score 3):

None, as far as I have ever heard of. There may be an instance out there of failure of both/all of the INS’s or displays, but in the airline world at least, it would have to be absurdly uncommon.

It is nice to have the standby ADI as a tie-breaker between the two primary displays in case they should happen to disagree (which was more likely with mechanical instruments than with electronic displays), but actually losing everything else & using just the standby to landing - between really rare and unheard of.

Comment: Thank you Ralph.
Seems to answer quite pretty well to the "exclusively" question... 
Maybe someone has more precise information about the "partially" question :-) ?

Comment: If you have at least 1 primary flight display, you aren’t really “partially” using the standby indicator for anything. If it’s all you have, then you’d be using it fully, but if you have something else, then THAT is what you’re fully focused on. I can’t come up with any scenario for partially using the standby ADI.